# How to fit very long line in case bracket equations in latex with double column

Tags: latex, equation

I have a double-column paper and I want to fit a long text within a bracket equation with the following code:

```
\begin{equation}
\small
M =\begin{cases*}
    1, & some text is in here some text is in here some text is in here some text is in here some text is in here some text is in here \\
    0, & otherwise\\
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation}
```

The text for case one goes over the column. I want to fit all the text for case one in multiple lines with the column width.

Comment: Can you please make a minimal working example that shows which documentclass you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add a `\parbox` of suitable width around the text:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

{
\small
\begin{equation}
M =\begin{cases*}
    1, & \parbox[t]{5.5cm}{some text is in here some text is in here some text is in here some text is in here some text is in here some text is in here} \\
    0, & otherwise\\
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation}}

\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

[image]

(please note that it is better to make font size changes outside of the `equation` environment)